# matplotlib, move annotation with draggable legend

Tags: matplotlib, annotations, draggable, legend

I'm trying to annotate the legend when passing on the legend text. This works but repeats the annotation, also when the legend is moved (leg.draggable(state=True)), the annotation repeats and i cannot remove it.

Here is a simplified code to reproduce the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#define functions
t = np.arange(0.0, 0.2, 0.1)
y1 = 2*np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
y2 = 4*np.sin(2*np.pi*2*t)

#define graphs
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line0, = ax.plot(t, y1, label='line0')
line1, = ax.plot(t, y2, label='line1')
leg = ax.legend(loc=2)
leg.draggable(state=True) #enable dragging legend

######################test mouse passing legend text#############
fig.canvas.draw()#draw first to get legend position

legtext = leg.get_texts()
line0 = legtext[0] #text of legend 0
line1 = legtext[1] #text of legend 1

def on_move(event):
    annotations = []

    if line0.contains(event)[0] == True:
        p = leg.get_window_extent()
        annotations.append(ax.annotate('Annotation Text 0', (p.p0[0], p.p1[1]), xycoords='figure pixels', zorder=9))
        # print 'line0', annotations
        fig.canvas.draw()
    elif line1.contains(event)[0] == True:
        p = leg.get_window_extent()
        annotations.append(ax.annotate('Annotation Text 1', (p.p0[0], p.p1[1]), xycoords='figure pixels', zorder=9))
        # print 'line1', annotations
        fig.canvas.draw()
    else:
        # print 'else', annotations
        for note in annotations:
            annotations[note].remove()
            # print 'annotation removed', annotations[note]
            fig.canvas.draw()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)

plt.show()
```

Can someone help me to remove the annotations when the mouse is not over the legend? Thanks you already.

Answer (score 0):

You were creating a list called `annotations`, appending or removing elements from it. What you want to do actually is to modify `ax.texts` which is a list containing all the annotations of your ax.

```
def on_move(event):

    if line0.contains(event)[0] == True:
        p = leg.get_window_extent()
        ax.annotate('Annotation Text 0', (p.p0[0], p.p1[1]), xycoords='figure pixels', zorder=9)

    elif line1.contains(event)[0] == True:
        p = leg.get_window_extent()
        ax.annotate('Annotation Text 1', (p.p0[0], p.p1[1]), xycoords='figure pixels', zorder=9)

    else:
        ax.texts = []

    fig.canvas.draw()
```

It works fine if you grab the legend box by the left, if you grab it by "line0" or "line1" you might see annotations appearing and disappearing while you move the legend. Hopefully it's ok. It stops as soon as you stop moving the legend box too.